# C++ /Cli program System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a odd problem

platform:.net 4.0, win7 32/64, VS2010

MIPCChannel.dll: C++/cli mixed dll

NewClient.exe: C# which refrenced the MIPCChannel.dll

The Problem is when i deploy my program, someone try to run NewClient.exe gives error:CLR20r3, System.BadImageFormatException

I do below steps:

1. i deference the  MIPCChannel.dll everything goes ok
2. or i install VS2010 redistribute everything goes ok

but i don't want to reply redistribute, and i want to know where the problem is!

Comment: so if you install VS2010 Redistributable, it works?

Comment: Why would you not want to redistribute?

Comment: yes, install VS2010 Redistributable it works. Redistribute will make my Client not so easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed mode C++/CLI DLLs must be linked against the dynamic runtime. That means you must deploy the dynamic runtime to any machine on which you hope to run such a DLL.

Since you are using VS2010, you don't need to deploy the runtime using the redistributable package, although that is the recommended way to do so. You can instead deploy [specific Visual C++ DLLs to the application local folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you, you are right, and i give up mixed mode C++/CLI dll, i tried  p/invoke

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is x86 or x64 problem. It is likely that you develop in 64 bit environment but deployed that in 32 bit environment.